# Asceticism vs. Monasticism

Tags: differences, synonyms, terminology

**What is the difference between asceticism and monasticism?**  It seems that in practice they are effectively synonymous; if this is the case, do they have differing origins?

I've included the first lines of each wikipedia entry below, which virtually identical.  For another example, in the wiki article for [Saint Anthony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_the_Great),

> "He is often erroneously considered the first monk, but as his biography and other sources make clear, there were many ascetics before him."

This again suggests the terms are effectively synonymous.

---

From [Asceticism wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asceticism):

> Asceticism (/əˈsɛtɪsɪz(ə)m/; from the Greek: ἄσκησις áskēsis, "exercise" or "training") is a lifestyle characterized by abstinence from various worldly pleasures, often with the aim of pursuing religious and spiritual goals.

From [Monasticism wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monasticism):

> Monasticism (from Greek μοναχός, monachos, derived from μόνος, monos, "alone") or monkhood is a religious way of life that involves renouncing worldly pursuits to fully devote one's self to spiritual work

Comment: Asceticism is personal, or may be part of something social. Monasticism, however, is definitely social, involving other monks and a canon, whether its practice is solitary or in a group.

Comment: Thank you @JohnLawler, that sounds great - and like a good 'answer'.  Can you point me towards any references?

Comment: Google "asceticism etymology" and "monasticism etymology" to see where they came from. That ought to clear it up.

Answer (score 2):

Just reading Wikipedia's definitions are fairly clear.

- Asceticism is abstaining from worldly **pleasures**, often (though not always) with a religious aim.
- Monasticism is a religious renunciation of worldly **pursuits**, to devote oneself to purely religious pursuits.

You can be a non-religious ascetic (such an atheist with a minimalist lifestyle), or a non-ascetic monk (such as the immediate past Pope).

Answer (score 0):

Asceticism means simplicity, physical self-denial, or lack of materialism. In the 80's, Jerry Brown was known for keeping an ascetic lifestyle as governor of California. He had a simple apartment in Sacramento with a mattress on the floor.

Monasticism means being a monk. Monastics don't have to be ascetics. Some monasteries are known for brewing beer. "Monastic" comes from Greek "monos," "alone," i.e., monastic communities set themselves apart from the rest of society.